# Laravel validation don't pass to blade

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I pulled project from repository to local environment. I face a problem that validation messages don't display on blade.

In my controller function, I can dump validation errors like this:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd($validator);
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

I took some time to search what can cause this issue and I found some results that my issue can be associated with web middleware.

Originally, my files looks like this:

RouteServiceProvider

```
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

Kernel

```
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

web.php

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@postRegister');
```

I tried to wrap my routes in web middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@postRegister');
});
```

Also I tried to move StartSession::class and ShareErrorsFromSession::class from middlewareGroups to middleware and removed middleware('web') from mapWebRoutes and problem still persists. Maybe someone faced same issue and was able to solve it?

My Laravel version is: 5.7.29, php version: 7.1.33

**Validation working on production**

Comment: How you display the error on your blade?

Comment: you forgot to put the most important part..... **the view**

Comment: I didn't include the view part, because it's working on production, so I don't think it has something with displaying in blade.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving back the $validator object you should return the `MessageBag` which you can get with `$validator->errors()`.

So your return statement will look like this:

`return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInputs()`

The MessageBag looks like this `['attrXY' => [error1,  error2, ...] ]`. The errors will automatically be available in your blade view in the `$errors` variable. (because of the withErrors() method)
You can either make a listing of all errors:

```php
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

or you can check if a specific error is present: `$errors->has('attrXY')` and display all the error messages for this attribute.

Most of these things and even more useful information can be found in the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my mistake I didn't explained it clearly - validation works on production site, so I don't think it has issue with blade or controller method. But I tried your solution too - still same problem.